# Java Mail API, при отправке почты используя SMTP не отображается письмо в отправленных

Tags: java, javamail

Используя Java Mail API , после отправки письма не отображается на почтовом ящике.

Вот код

```
public class MailAPI {
    static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    public static void sendMessage(String emailSender, String passwordSender, String emailRecipient, String subject)
            throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String content = "Some words";
        String smtpHost= "smtp.yandex.ru";
        String smtpPort="465";
        sendSimpleMessage (emailSender, passwordSender, emailSender, emailRecipient, content, subject, smtpPort, smtpHost);
    }

    public static void sendSimpleMessage(String login, String password, String from, String to, String content,
                                         String subject, String smtpPort, String smtpHost)
                                        throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Authenticator auth = new MyAuthenticator(login, password);

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.mime.charset", ENCODING);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(content);
        Transport.send(msg);

    }
}
```

Comment: А разве должно? SMTP пересылает письмо на почтовый сервер получателя. И ничего не знает о почтовых ящиках отправителя. Ящик предоставляет почтовая программа, специально для этого разработанная. При отправке письма сохраняет его в ящике и по SMTP пересылает на сервер получателя. Примерно так.

Answer (score 3):

SMTP не должен сохранять отправленные сообщения на сервере, обычно почтовые клиенты сделаны таким образом, что они сами сохраняют отправленные сообщения в своей локальной базе. Либо некоторые сервера представляют такое "удобство" дополнительно к отправке письма. Вам нужно отправит письмо с помощью smtp, а затем сохранить его в папке "оправленные", например с помощью imap протокола с помощью метода [com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.addMessages()](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#addMessages-javax.mail.Message:A-)

Comment: т.е. мы должны отнаследоваться от класса IMAPFolder, после перейти в нужную папку и методом addMessage() добавить туда отправленное сообщение?

Comment: Например, посмотрите [здесь](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=current-master/hupa/server/src/main/java/org/apache/hupa/server/handler/AbstractSendMessageHandler.java). Там есть методы `sendMessage` и `saveSentMessage`. Вообще в Google поищите примеры.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [SMTP-сервер Gmail](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=ru) Он сохраняет письма в папке "Отправленные".